# SBT on IntelliJ takes a very long to time refresh

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a fairly large project (15+ subprojects) which has a lot of external dependencies. When I change even a single line in `build.sbt` and then hit refresh, IntelliJ keeps on resolving various dependencies for a very long time (30+ minutes).

Is it supposed to be this slow? Using sbt from command line does not take more than 30 secs or so.

I am using -

```
Macbook pro mid 2015 with 16 GB ram
IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.2.5
sbt 0.13.13 
scala 2.11.11
```

Comment: Do you have  "Download sbt sources" option disabled? Also you could try to enable "Use SBT shell for build and import" option.

Comment: "Download SBT sources" is unchecked. "Download library sources" is checked though. Hey, SBT shell did the trick. THANK YOU SO MUCH :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I enabled SBT shell inside IntelliJ as suggested by @y.bedrov and now the refresh is as fast as command line!

Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > SBT > check "Use SBT shell for build and import".

Comment: FWIW, enabling this makes my build refresh longer. Probably (among other things) because it does project load twice, at start and then issues a `reload` command. My build is quite big (50+ projects), so, I guess, actual set of optimizations one should use depends on the build size. Anyway, great if it helps you.

Answer (score 8):

One thing can help is cached dependency resolution, which is a setting available starting from sbt 0.13.7. Have a look here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Cached-Resolution.html, but basically you need to enable the following setting for all of the projects in your build:

```
updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)
```

I was able to cut down IntelliJ project refresh time from 15 minutes to 3 minutes with this setting. Still not ideal, but way more manageable.

There are some caveats, since it's an experimental setting, they're described in that page. Basically, if you have SNAPSHOT dependencies, enabling this will only make things worse, so be conscious of that.

Comment: Thank you. I have enabled SBT shell for now and the refresh time is down to a few minutes. I will try the cached resolution too, and update here if it helps even more.

Answer (score 5):

Kakaji and Haspemulator's answers helped me take the import down to ~3 minutes on a ~40 project build. In addition to that I found out that most of the time in the IntelliJ SBT import was spent fetching the dependencies from Ivy as part of the `updateClassifiers` command.

This happens every time you perform the import if you have the 'Library Sources' checkbox enabled when you import the project. I would expect it to be slower if you also check 'sbt sources' because that means more libraries to resolve.

One way to speed up `updateClassifiers` is to use [coursier](https://github.com/coursier/coursier) for dependency resolution. I just added the following line to project/plugins.sbt and now it imports in ~1 minute.

```
addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "1.0.1")
```

You can read more about `updateClassifiers` being slow at https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1930

Answer (score 1):

I am using the combination of the 2 above ( 
 - Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > SBT > check "Use SBT shell for build and import"
 - coursier

with the following global build.sbt :

```
    // file: ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt
    // purpose: add jar utils useful for development, but not wanted to projects' build.sbt

    // much better depts resolvement and fetching
    // usage: sbt update
    // https://github.com/coursier/coursier#why
    resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
    addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "1.1.0-SNAPSHOT")


    // enable this one if you want to use the local artifacts in your local repo's
    // ~/.ivy2/local/
    // ~/.ivy2/cache/
    // instead of the remote ones
    // updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withLatestSnapshots(false)


    resolvers ++= Seq(
       "typesafe" at "https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/",
       "Maven External Releases" at "https://artifactory-espoo1.ext.net.nokia.com/artifactory/public-maven-remotes/"
    )


    // eof file: ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt
```